# Parse XML File and display the Text

Tags: xml, parsing, powershell, batch-file

I've a XML file that is updated often, and I would like to write a script (PowerShell or Batch File) that would show what version is it.

`<rules version="240">` is the very first line of the file.
I would like to parse `240` and output it on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Good for [@FoxDeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32276204/1683264) for being the only other answerer to suggest parsing the XML as XML, rather than tokenizing and scraping it as flat text.  Here's a variation of his method.

If the XML structure doesn't strictly follow the XML standard, the `Microsoft.XMLDOM` COM object is a little more tolerant of loose formatting.  Here's another PowerShell alternative.

```js
$xml = new-object -COM Microsoft.XMLDOM
[void]$xml.load('desktop\test.xml')
$xml.async = 0
$xml.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath')
$xml.documentElement.selectSingleNode('//rules').getAttribute('version')
```

Or if you want it in a batch script, using the same COM object in Windows Scripting Host via a JScript chimera would execute more quickly if firing from a cmd console or double-click.  (Save this with a .bat extension.)

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

for /f %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:Jscript "%~f0" "%CD%\test.xml"') do set "%%I"

set version
set /P "=Press any key to exit..."<NUL & pause >NUL & echo;

goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript

var DOM = WSH.CreateObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');

with (DOM) {
    load(WSH.Arguments(0));
    async = false;
    setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
}

var rules = DOM.documentElement.selectSingleNode('//rules');
WSH.Echo('version=' + rules.getAttribute('version'));
```

Comment: I've never seen that object before.  I like it!  The most difficult part about getting PowerShell to parse an XML file is the malformed XML files everyone seems to be using, these days.  For what it's worth, I like your example of using XPAth to find a single node.  I'd never seen someone use .getAttribute either, I like it!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have a file similar to this, called books.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?rules version="240"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
```

PowerShell can natively parse XML files very easily, using the Get-Content command and specifying as [xml].

```
 [xml](Get-Content .\book.xml)

xml           rules         catalog
---           -----         -------
version="1.0" version="240" catalog
```

From this point, you can easily select the version by using the Select cmdlet.

```
[xml](Get-Content .\book.xml) | select -expand Rules
version="240"
```

In this example, I've got a few book.xml files, each with a different version.

```
 Dir book* | ForEach {(Get-Content $_.FullName) -as [xml]}

xml           rules         catalog
---           -----         -------
version="1.0" version="240" catalog
version="1.0" version="250" catalog
version="1.0" version="350" catalog
```

Comment: Good for you for parsing XML *as* XML rather than scraping and tokenizing it as flat text.  Nice explanation and breakdown as well.  And actually, if the `rules` node is a body node (as opposed to the `<?meta?>` type you have in your assumption), one might even code golf the following solution: `([xml](gc test.xml)).Rules.version`

Answer (score 0):

Try sed!

```
more <insert your xml file here> | grep 'rules version' | sed 's/.\+\<rules version=\"//g' | sed 's/".\+$//g'ere
```

Comment: Thank you! Can sed be used to copy files to other locations? Not familiar with it. Because depending on the version no, file is going to be moved.

Answer (score 0):

This should do.

```
     for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%A in ('findstr /n . input.txt ^| findstr /b ^^1:')do  @echo %%A
```

Output:

```
    240
```